# Stored Procedure Running Slow in ColdFusion 9

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a stored procedure that started to run really slow since yesterday and I can't find out why. I am running the SP directly in SQL Management Studio and it takes +/- 6 seconds to return the results but when I am running the same thing from a script it takes 40+ seconds to return the same thing. No code/queries were changed at all.
I tried restarting the servers and the CF application server with no success. Anyone with any ideas about how to debug this thing?

I created a small script just to run the SP alone and here is the code.

```
 <cfquery name="results" datasource="#ds#">
            DECLARE @owners Table (ownerid varchar(50) NULL,category varchar(50) NULL);
            insert into @owners (ownerid, category)
            exec survey.dbo.sp_FilteredOwners
                '2014-06-30 00:00:00.0',
                '2014-07-01 23:59:59.9',
                '35',
                '2008013110482896439177,2010080209524690985587',
                'F4EF72AF-C0C9-FF31-14CE48E082472995,19C963DD-9C1D-91B5-6B7A707C95EEFDDA',
                'ABREGOJE,ACCAJ,AFSHARPOURA,AGUAYOC',
                'AACHENWINANSJ,ABREGOJE,ACCAJ,ADAMSB',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                'Eyebrow,Follicular Unit Extraction,Graft Removal/Reimplantation,Hair Transplantation,Scar Revision,Test Survey,Unassigned'

           DECLARE @o2 Table (ownerid varchar(50) NULL,category varchar(50) NULL, tag varchar(50) NULL);
              insert into @o2 (ownerid, category, tag)
              select ownerid, category, max(questiontag)
              from @owners o
              join survey.dbo.results r on o.ownerid = r.owneridfk
              left join survey.dbo.questionsadmin qa on r.answeridfk = qa.answeridfk and qa.tagidfk in (102,105,117,123,132)
              left join survey.dbo.questiontags qt on qa.tagidfk = qt.id
              group by ownerid, category

            select distinct
            o.category as category, o.category as status,
            o.tag,
            s.name, st.surveyeventid,
            c.contactid as contactid, c.first, c.last,
            sr.completed as datecomplete, st.ownerIdfk, st.finalScore, st.surveyid,
            cc.clientcontactid, cc.leadsource,
            se.eventdate, se.ProcedureName, clm.LocationName, se.salesperson, se.SpecialistName, stm.surveytitle,
            sst.statusname, st.serviceRepID, rep.sr_name
            from @o2 o
            join survey.dbo.survey_results sr on o.ownerid = sr.ownerid
            join survey.dbo.surveys s on sr.surveyidfk = s.id
            join sigweb.dbo.survey_tracking st on o.ownerid = st.owneridfk
            join survey.dbo.survey_events se on st.surveyeventid = se.id
            join survey.dbo.client_contacts cc on sr.contactid = cc.contactidfk
            join sigweb.dbo.contact c on sr.contactid = c.contactid
            join sigweb.dbo.survey_types_main stm on sr.surveyidfk =  stm.surveyidfk
            join sigweb.dbo.survey_statusTypes sst on st.surveyStatusID = sst.statusID
            join survey.dbo.clientlocationmap clm on se.doctorid = clm.doctorid and clm.clientbrandid = '35'
            left join sigweb.dbo.servicereps rep on st.servicerepid = rep.servrepid
            order by sr.completed desc

        </cfquery>

        <cfdump var='#results#'>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `<cfstoredproc >`?

Comment: this is just something I created now on the fly just to run this piece of code alone. I am new to the SP all together so I will check it out. So far from the tests that I am running it seems like the CF is having  some trouble communicating with my DB server.

Comment: How are you measuring the execution times?

Comment: @DanBracuk in CF I am using `GetTickCount()` or when I dump the query I check the execution time that comes with the dump and in SQL management studio it is telling you on the bottom of the screen how long it took for the results to get back.

Comment: How long does it take to run a simple query, such as "select 1 record" or "select count(*) records from some_small_table"?.

Comment: @DanBracuk Some miliseconds. Why?

Comment: I had an issue like this crop up because the application was using different SET options than when I ran via SSMS.  Use the method in [this page](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/) to test the options in each, and make sure they are the same.

Comment: @unit3524344 Now that I checked it again `<cfstoredproc>` has some limitations when you need to do joins on other tables because the results of `<cfstoredproc>` will end up being a queryOfqueries

Comment: Why would you not just put the joins into the query being run by the stored proc?

Comment: The purpose of the simple queries was to test your theory about coldfusion communicating to the database.

Comment: @DanBracuk CF is communicating but it is really slow (close to 10x slower) and just the SP part of the site. Everything else that is just a regular query is running fine

Comment: @DanBracuk Also, I can't put the joins in the SP because the joins are depending on which function is using the SP because I get the SP's results and then I do different ops each time

Comment: I fixed the issue somehow by dropping and recreating the SP and everything is back to normal. Any ideas what can cause this kind of behavior? @DanBracuk

Comment: Sounds like one of life's little mysteries.

Comment: Check your execution plan. That usually tells you what the issue is. Why it's suddenly *changed* is a different thing.